# Activating Redmine's roadmap

Tags: redmine

I recently installed Redmine and started configuring a plethora of items such as roles, statuses, projects, issues, and that kind of good stuff. But to my surprise I found no section for clustering issues into roadmaps. I've searched everywhere in the Administration's settings and there's nothing that could activate the section "Roadmaps" in Redmine's projects.

I'd appreciate some pointers as to what I have to do to activate roadmaps, be either by assigning permissions to roles or by changing settings.

Comment: If you'd like something that builds on the versions and makes them much more usable, try the backlogs plugin.  It has a number of prerequisites that you need to get right, but once installed it makes routing issues to versions (or sprints, in scrum parlance) much easier to manage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to use Roadmaps you need to have versions.

Go into Project->Settings then choose versions and add a new version.

The roadmap options should then become visible.

Not very intuitive.